# Zookeeper java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector

Tags: jetty, hbase, apache-zookeeper, openjdk-11

I am getting the below error when starting Apache HBase with Zookeeper on my mac. I am using openjdk11.

```
./start-hbase.sh
```

```
*************  WARN  [main] admin.AdminServerFactory: Unable to load jetty, not starting JettyAdminServer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.admin.AdminServerFactory.createAdminServer(AdminServerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.runZKServer(HQuorumPeer.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 6 more
```

Can anyone help me with what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your classloader is missing the required Jetty jars.

In this case, the class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector` is contained in the `jetty-server-<ver>.jar` (in a traditional Jetty installation).

You should edit your question and include *how* you are starting zookeeper/hbase, as much detail as you can, as that could give people clues on how to help you address this issue.